# How to return a template pack nested in other pack?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, pack

The following code works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

struct Base {};
struct A : Base {};  struct B : Base {};  struct C : Base {};
struct D : Base {};  struct E : Base {};  struct F : Base {};

template <int KEY, typename... RANGE> struct Map {};  // one-to-many map (mapping KEY to RANGE...)

template <typename...> struct Data {};

using Database = Data<  Map<0, A,B,C>, Map<1, D,E,F>  >;

template <int N, typename FIRST, typename... REST>  // N has meaning in my program, but not shown here.
void insertInMenu (std::list<Base*>& menu) {
    menu.push_back(new FIRST);
    insertInMenu<N, REST...> (menu);
}

template <int N>
void insertInMenu (std::list<Base*>&) {}  // End of recursion.

template <int N>
std::list<Base*> menu() {
    std::list<Base*> m;
    insertInMenu<0, A,B,C>(m);  // A,B,C should be obtained using N and Database.
    return m;
}

int main() {
    std::list<Base*> m = menu<0>();
    std::cout << "m.size() = " << m.size() << std::endl;  // 3
}
```

But as indicated in my comment above, I want to use `Database` and the value `N` to obtain the range `A,B,C` (or `D,E,F`) or whatever.  But I don't know how to do that?  Can anyone help?
The line

```
insertInMenu<0, A,B,C>(m);
```

needs to be replaced with something like

```
obtainRange<Database, N>()
```

since those compile-time known values should be enough information to obtain the range I want.

```
obtainRange<Database, 0>()
```

should return `A,B,C` and

```
obtainRange<Database, 1>()
```

should return `D,E,F` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <typename D, int N>
struct obtainRange;

template <int N, typename... Ts, typename... Maps>
struct obtainRange<Data<Map<N, Ts...>, Maps...>, N>
{
    using type = std::tuple<Ts...>;
};

template <int N, int M, typename... Ts, typename... Maps>
struct obtainRange<Data<Map<M, Ts...>, Maps...>, N>
    : obtainRange<Data<Maps...>, N> {};

template <int N, typename Tuple, std::size_t... Is>
std::list<Base*> menu(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    std::list<Base*> m;
    insertInMenu<0, typename std::tuple_element<Is, Tuple>::type...>(m);
    return m;
}

template <int N>
std::list<Base*> menu()
{    
    using Tuple = typename obtainRange<Database, N>::type;
    return menu<N, Tuple>(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>{});
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ea95ab3d22e07a7)

---

If you can't use [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) `std::index_sequence`, then below is an alternative [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) compatible implementation:

```
template <std::size_t... Is>
struct index_sequence {};

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
struct make_index_sequence_h : make_index_sequence_h<N - 1, N - 1, Is...> {};

template <std::size_t... Is>
struct make_index_sequence_h<0, Is...>
{
    using type = index_sequence<Is...>;
};

template <std::size_t N>
using make_index_sequence = typename make_index_sequence_h<N>::type;
```

---

You can go further, and make it working with arbitrary templates similar to `Data` and `Map`, e.g. a `std::tuple` (instead of `Data`) of `Map`s, using *template template-parameters*:

```
template <typename D, int N>
struct obtainRange;

template <template <typename...> class DB
        , template <int, typename...> class MP
        , typename... Ts
        , typename... Maps
        , int N>
struct obtainRange<DB<MP<N, Ts...>, Maps...>, N>
{
    using type = std::tuple<Ts...>;
};

template <template <typename...> class DB
        , template <int, typename...> class MP
        , typename... Ts
        , typename... Maps
        , int M
        , int N>
struct obtainRange<DB<MP<M, Ts...>, Maps...>, N> : obtainRange<DB<Maps...>, N> {};
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6b416de45cab4eb)

Answer (score 1):

```
// There is no need to take the length here, btw.
template <int, typename... Args>
void insertInMenu (std::list<Base*>& menu)
{
    // Non-recursive push_backs:
    std::initializer_list<int>{ (menu.push_back(new Args), 0)... };
}

template <int, typename> struct InsertEnv;

template <int key, int otherKey, typename... Args, typename... Rest>
struct InsertEnv<key, Data<Map<otherKey, Args...>, Rest...>> :
    InsertEnv<key, Data<Rest...>> {};

template <int key, typename... Args, typename... Rest>
struct InsertEnv<key, Data<Map<key, Args...>, Rest...>>
{
    void operator()(std::list<Base*>& menu)
    {
        insertInMenu<key, Args...> (menu);
    }

    std::list<Base*> operator()()
    {
        return {new Args...};
    }
};

template <int N>
void addToMenu (std::list<Base*>& menu)
{
    InsertEnv<N, Database>()(menu);
}

template <int N>
std::list<Base*> menu()
{
    return InsertEnv<N, Database>()();
}
```

User either as

```
menu<N>() // list with the desired elements in it
```

Or as

```
std::list<Base*> list;
addToMenu<N>(list); // pushes back the desired elements
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3d7c1a704dfa107).

Comment: where are you selecting a `Map` from `Database` based on its index ?

Comment: @PiotrS. Typo. Fixed.

Comment: I meant that `insertInMenu<1, Data<Map<0,A,B>,Map<1,C,D>>` should result with `C,D` (map indexed as `1` in `Database`), not expanding `Map<0,AB>,Map<1,C,D>`

Comment: @PiotrS. Did it accordingly to the list, does it look correct to you?

Answer (score 1):

[Live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b74ee52def39a8a)

```
template <typename, int>
struct obtainRange {};

template <int N, typename...Types, typename...Rest>
struct obtainRange<Data<Map<N, Types...>, Rest...>, N> :
    Data<Types...> {};

template <int N, typename T, typename...Rest>
struct obtainRange<Data<T, Rest...>, N> : 
    obtainRange<Data<Rest...>, N> {};

template <typename...Types>
std::list<Base*> menu(Data<Types...>) {
    return { new Types{}... };
}

template <int N>
std::list<Base*> menu() {
    return menu(obtainRange<Database, N>{});
}
```

Comment: This short solution works perfectly with std::list, but my container is actually a specialized class so I still need to use insertInMenu to handle that special container.  But it is good to see a nice quick solution for the special case of an STL container.

Comment: @prestokeys It's not exactly a special case - it will work with any container that can be constructed from a braced-init-list of `Base*` - but in fairness falls apart in a real program when you substitute `unique_ptr<Base>` for `Base*` since you can't move elements from a `std::initializer_list`.